What can we say about the average order of group members of alternating group?
During an ongoing research I dealt with the concept of orders of group members. The following question remained a gap in my analysis. Any insight is appreciated.
Let $ \bar{o}(G) $ be the average order of the elements of $ G $, where $ G $
is a finite group.
Let $ A_n $ be the alternating group of degree $ n $. Then
\begin{align*}
&        \bar{o}(A_3)\simeq 2.33,   \quad  \quad  \bar{o}(A_4)\simeq 2.58, \quad \quad     \bar{o}(A_5)\simeq 3.51,  \quad\quad     \bar{o}(A_6)\simeq 3.91, \\
&        \bar{o}(A_7)\simeq 5.00,   \quad  \quad  \bar{o}(A_8)\simeq 6.79,  \quad  \quad    \bar{o}(A_9)\simeq 8.35,  \quad \quad    \bar{o}(A_{10})\simeq 9.98, \\
&        \bar{o}(A_{11})\simeq 11.18,   \quad    \bar{o}(A_{12})\simeq 12.41, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{13})\simeq 14.86, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{14})\simeq 19.17, \\
&          \bar{o}(A_{15})\simeq  24.04,  \quad      \bar{o}(A_{16})\simeq  27.97,  \quad     \bar{o}(A_{17})\simeq 29.11,   \quad    \bar{o}(A_{18})\simeq 32.01,  \\
&         \bar{o}(A_{19})\simeq  37.56, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{20})\simeq  43.47, \quad \bar{o}(A_{21})\simeq  54.14, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{22})\simeq  63.11,
 \\
&         \bar{o}(A_{23})\simeq  66.35, \quad      \bar{o}(A_{24})\simeq  70.22, \quad \bar{o}(A_{25})\simeq  81.97.
 \end{align*}
My question:
If $n \geqslant 13$, show that $\bar{o}(A_{n}) >  n+1$

For the alternating group, it should be relatively straightforward to sort the elements of a given order given the disjoint cycle decompositions.

This paper (W. Goh, E. Schmutz, The expected order of a random permutation. Bull. LMS 23(1), 34-42, 1991) deals with the average of orders of elements in the symmetric group (and mentions results of Erdös etc). It's about $n^{\log n/2}$. This should be similar in the alternating group, you can maybe try to prove it.
